# How to group multiple messages in elastic query. Is it grouped by default?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

The below query works absolutley fine but I want these messages to be grouped. Which means I would like "No DB record found for Category:" messages logged first and then the "Not all codes match in DB for Category:". I tested this with small number of messages and they appear to be grouped which is what i wanted. But i'm wondering if that will work for large number of records.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-1h/h"}}},
      "minimum_should_match": 1,                                  <---- ADD THIS
      "should": [
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "No DB record found for Category:"}},
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "Not all codes match in DB for Category:" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is based on `_score` parameter. It is mostly depends on data. And scoring model of elastic is `Lucene`'s one. [scoring](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/)

To order the results, you can use sort on message field. It looks like `message` is of type `keyword`.

Comment: By default, it appears to be grouped by the match_phrase.